# Tower defense make a tower face a monster spritebatch rotation

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, spritebatch

This is my code for drawing the tower:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(
    GetTowerImage(m.SquareTower), 
    new Rectangle(m.X * TILE_SIZE, m.Y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE), 
    null, 
    Color.White, 
    m.SquareTower.Rotation, 
    new Vector2(TILE_SIZE - 35, TILE_SIZE - 35), 
    SpriteEffects.None, 
    (float)0.0);
```

My code that gets the position of a tower and places it in a position, however when my rotation method takes place and rotates the image

```
public void FaceTarget(Vector2 center, Vector2 enemyCenter)
        {
            Vector2 direction = center - enemyCenter;
            direction.Normalize();

            this.Rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(-direction.X, direction.Y);
        }
```

I did this based on:

- http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Rotation.php
- http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Direction_to_Angle.php

The rotation is being really weird, here is how it looks normally:

[image]

But when it rotates it goes like this:

[image]

Finally when it looks down, it goes complete off path, it's not rotating by its center, but the entire image is moving why is it doing that?

[image]

Only the first image is actually the tower in the correct position

(I don't have enough reputation to post images)

Comment: Are you sure the origin of rotation is correct? That should be the center of your tower (e.g. `new Vector2(TILE_SIZE - TILE_SIZE/2, TILE_SIZE - TILE_SIZE/2)`)

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but my reputation is too low... sorry. 
By the looks of it I'm pretty positive that your origin is your tower's X and Y position, it really should be something like this:

```
// AKA the centre of your tower relative to it's Vector2 position
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(towerWidth / 2, towerHeight / 2);
```